# PowerShell call function on enter in a textbox

Tags: powershell, eventhandler

I'm trying to validate a user input made in a textbox. But instead of always adding a button that he has to press i would like to check it automatically when the user hits the "Enter"-Key.

So my question is:
Can PowerShell call a function as soon as the user hits the Enter in a specific textbox?

Comment: Hi, WinForms or WPF? Can you please show your GUI code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple example in Windows Forms:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

$textbox.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq [System.Windows.Forms.Keys]::Enter) {
        #logic
        $textbox.Text | Out-Host
    }
})

$form.Controls.Add($textbox)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Brilliant. I have a question though. Is there a way to keep the cursor in the same position after pressing Enter key?

Comment: @Nawad-sama I don't understand your question, I've run my example and the cursor does not move when I press Enter